# Forward declaring a function template with a non type template parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++17, sfinae

Given the following program

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value>*>
void foo(T&&);
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(T&&) {}

int main() {
    foo(int{});
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/rlASqofr0Is38lop

Clang compiles this code just fine (https://wandbox.org/permlink/xCfDNvTlYD2x7WG3), but gcc gives an error saying that it could not deduce the anonymous template parameter.  Who is right?

---

I looked in the standard in the function templates section `[temp.fct]` and found something similar.  There was a section about which function template is preferred when using we have two identical function templates with differing name lookups - does the anonymous non type template parameter constitute as a "dependent name"?  This was the relevant text in the standard

> For determining whether two dependent names (17.6.2) are equivalent, only the name itself is considered, not the result of name lookup in the context of the template. If multiple declarations of the same function template differ in the result of this name lookup, the result for the first declaration is used.
>
> ```
> template <class T> decltype(g(T())) h();
> int g(int);
> template <class T> decltype(g(T())) h()
>   { return g(T()); }
> int i = h<int>();
> ```

Given the two identical function templates in the example above, if the first is preferred does the same apply here in my case?  Where is the name lookup happening in my case? Does that mean clang is wrong?

Why does this program compile - https://wandbox.org/permlink/I0tcHTPvGMWbdpC3?  Is this because here the first name is considered and after template deduction is done we call the definition of the same function template?

Answer (score 1):

I think Clang is correct here.

From [temp.param/10]:

> The set of default *template-arguments* available for use is obtained by
>   merging the default arguments from all prior declarations of the
>   template in the same way default function arguments are (11.3.6). [
>   *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2 = int> class A;
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class A;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2 = int> class A;
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

In your example, you have two declarations of the template `foo` (see [temp/1]), so they should be equivalent to:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, int>::value>* = nullptr>
void foo(T&&) {}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to make of this :( Do you know why my interpretation is incorrect?